# Is there a way to catch a STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN error programmatically?

Tags: seh, buffer-overrun

We have some C code that is throwing a `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN` error (`0xC0000409`) once in a while.  I can reproduce that error using the C code below.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 on Windows 7, and I'm compiling with the [/EHa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5(v=vs.120).aspx) and [/GS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c(v=vs.120).aspx) flags. However, I have been unable to catch the error programmatically. The code never enters my `__except` block; instead, Visual Studio pops up a few dialog boxes informing me of the stack corruption.  I realize that once this error occurs, the state of the program is in doubt; I'm merely trying to capture the error in hopes of locating where it is occurring in our production code.  Is there a way to handle this error programmatically?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996) // strcpy

void vulnerable(const char* str)
{
   char buffer[10];
   strcpy(buffer, str); // overrun the buffer
}

int main()
{
   __try
   {
      char large_buffer[] = "This string is longer than 10 characters.";
      vulnerable(large_buffer);
   }
   __except (GetExceptionCode() == STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)
   {
      printf("error"); // never getting here
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't; overrunning the buffer is not guarenteed to trigger an error. Redesign your function to not rely on this.

Comment: The CRT implementation assumes that the process was compromised.  So SEH cannot be trusted anymore either.  It intentionally bypasses it and ensures that a exception handler installed with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() cannot see it either.  All you can get is a debugger break.  Which is of course the proper way to fix this bug.

Comment: What are `__try` and `__except`? That is no standard C.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for your answer.  Our code is running on a machine that doesn't have a debugger installed, and putting a debugger on the machine isn't an option, so if a debugger break is the only way to "capture" the error, do you have any thoughts as to how I can start narrowing down where this error is occurring?